# Trouble adding inline Javascript into a page

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to do work for a client and am having a lot of trouble, so some help would be appreciated!

They have a store, and that 3rd-party called RangeWorks that provides code like the following to embed purchasing and scheduling (business name changed for anonymity):

```
    <div id="rangegenius-class" class="section-normal" style="background-color:transparent;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rangeworks.us/rangegenius_iframe.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.RangeGenius.init({
        id: "rangegenius-class",
        business: "business-name",
        module: "training/1",
        seamless: true,
        loader: true
      });
</script>
```

I have tried pasting that code into the Source of a Drupal page, and then when I View Source, I do get this CDATA comment around it:

```
 <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><div class="section-normal" id="rangegenius-class" style="background-color:transparent;"> </div><script type="text/javascript" src="https://rangeworks.us/rangegenius_iframe.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[// ><!--

      window.RangeGenius.init({
        id: "rangegenius-class",
        business: "business-name",
        module: "training/1",
        seamless: true,
        loader: true
      });

//--><!]]>
</script></div></div></div>  </div>
```

Basically, I'm not getting the membership stuff coming through - just the services loading animation jumping around, and nothing loads up.

In my JS console, I do see:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     rangeworks.us/rgapi/business-name/classes/1

404 - Not Found         main.35041x... .v2.bundle.js:1

Navigated to https://www.business-name.com/classes

GET https://rangeworks.us/rgapi/business-name/classes/1 404 (Not Found)    polyfills.b8ce37e... v2.bundle.js:1     

404 - Not Found     main.35041c3... .v2.bundle.js:1
```

I don't really know if this is an issue on RangeWorks end, or on my end in Drupal. I did contact RangeWorks asking about help with this, but I'm scrambling here and wanted to see if anyone could at least point me in the right direction.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like it is saying this URL does not exist: rangeworks.us/rgapi/business-name/classes/1. You get the same error if you view it in the browser. https://rangeworks.us/rgapi/business-name/classes/1

Comment: At the same time, you will want to look into not having Javascript code right in the template file, and be in a JS file included via drupal_add_js() in a preprocess function before the template is rendered.

Comment: Yeah, what's (I'm assuming) even worse is I'm just clicking the source button in the WYSIWYG editor and pasting this code in. The issue is that this is only going on one page - and other widgets need to be embedded on other pages throughout the site.

Comment: Not best practice.

Comment: See [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7). If this needs to be loaded on all pages go with method 1, else if only specific pages go with method 2.